# Jersey: InjectableProvider not picked up - Spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey, servlet-filters, injectableprovider

I am currently trying to create an `InjectableProvider` with Jersey, but I cannot get Jersey to pick it up.

I cannot find any real examples of its usage, or even how to get it picked up besides using the `@Provider` annotation on the implementation. The person that seemingly wrote it within Jersey implied in some posts that this is enough to have it picked up.

Do I need to specify some SPI service file, or add it to some factory somewhere?

Note: I am running within Glassfish 3.1, and using Spring 3.1. It seems reasonable that Spring may be somehow taking over for the automatic loading of the `Provider`s. However, I just don't know. I am not using Spring in anyway to manage the suggested InjectableProvider below, nor am I trying to add it in some other way, which may-well be my problem.

```
import com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentContext;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Injectable;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider;

public abstract class AbstractAttributeInjectableProvider<T>
        extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<AttributeParam, T>
{
    protected final Class<T> type;

    public AbstractAttributeInjectableProvider(Class<T> type)
    {
        super(type);

        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Injectable<T> getInjectable(ComponentContext componentContext,
                                       AttributeParam attributeParam)
    {
        return new AttributeInjectable<T>(type, attributeParam.value());
    }
}
```

Basic Implementation:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Component // <- Spring Annotation
@Provider  // <- Jersey Annotation
public class MyTypeAttributeInjectableProvider
        extends AbstractAttributeInjectableProvider<MyType>
{
    public MyTypeAttributeInjectableProvider()
    {
        super(MyType.class);
    }
}
```

Reference `Annotation`:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface AttributeParam
{
    /**
     * The value is the name to request as an attribute from an {@link
     * HttpContext}'s {@link HttpServletRequest}.
     * @return Never {@code null}. Should never be blank.
     */
    String value();
}
```

Reference [link from Jersey developer](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Injected-into-hell-td680228.html).

---

**UPDATE**: calvinkrishy pointed out two flaws to my thinking.

First, I assumed that Jersey was going to kick off scanning for `@Provider`s after being kicked off by the traditional Jersey-Spring servlet: `com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet`. This was mostly incorrect; it does start scanning, but it looks for Spring beans that have the annotation.

Second, I assumed that the `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` would be asked upon each incoming request for an `Injectable` to handle the annotation that it controls. This too was wrong. The `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` is instantiated upon startup, as expected, but Jersey then immediately asks for `Injectable`'s to handle the given annotation with the given `type`, which it determines by scanning the Restful Services that it has--at this point--decided that it manages (which is to say, all of them).

The difference between the `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` and `SingletonTypeInjectableProvider` seems to be that the resulting `Injectable` either contains the value without working for it (singleton), or it looks it up each time for the value (per request), thus enabling the value to change per request.

This threw a smaller wrench into my plans by forcing me to do some extra work in my `AttributeInjectable` (code below) rather than passing in some objects, as I had planned, to avoid giving the `AttributeInjectable` extra knowledge.

```
public class AttributeInjectable<T> implements Injectable<T>
{
    /**
     * The type of data that is being requested.
     */
    private final Class<T> type;
    /**
     * The name to extract from the {@link HttpServletRequest} attributes.
     */
    private final String name;

    /**
     * Converts the attribute with the given {@code name} into the {@code type}.
     * @param type The type of data being retrieved
     * @param name The name being retrieved.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any parameter is {@code null}.
     */
    public AttributeInjectable(Class<T> type, String name)
    {
        // check for null

        // required
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Look up the requested value.
     * @return {@code null} if the attribute does not exist or if it is not the
     *         appropriate {@link Class type}.
     *         <p />
     *         Note: Jersey most likely will fail if the value is {@code null}.
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@link HttpServletRequest} is unset.
     * @see #getRequest()
     */
    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        T value = null;
        Object object = getRequest().getAttribute(name);

        if (type.isInstance(object))
        {
            value = type.cast(object);
        }

        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current {@link HttpServletRequest} [hopefully] being made
     * containing the {@link HttpServletRequest#getAttribute(String) attribute}.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the Servlet Filter for the {@link
     *                              RequestContextHolder} is not setup
     *                              appropriately.
     * @see org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter
     */
    protected HttpServletRequest getRequest()
    {
        // get the request from the Spring Context Holder (this is done for
        //  every request by a filter)
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes =
            (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

        return attributes.getRequest();
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to pass in the `HttpServletRequest` from the `Provider`, but the `AttributeInjectable` is only instantiated per unique annotation/type. As I cannot do that, I do that per value lookup, which uses Spring's `RequestContextFilter` singleton, which provides a `ThreadLocal` mechanism for safely retrieving the `HttpServletRequest` (among other things related to the current request).

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/that/i/wanted/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The result does work, and it makes the code much more readable without forcing various services to extend a base class just to hide the usage of `@Context HttpServletRequest request`, which is then used to access the attributes as done above through some helper method.

Then you can do something along the lines of this:

```
@Path("my/path/to")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public interface MyService
{
    @Path("service1")
    @POST
    Response postData(@AttributeParam("some.name") MyType data);

    @Path("service2")
    @POST
    Response postOtherData(@AttributeParam("other.name") MyOtherType data);
}

@Component // Spring
public class MyServiceBean implements MyService
{
    @Override
    public Response postData(MyType data)
    {
        // interact with data
    }

    @Override
    public Response postOtherData(MyOtherType data)
    {
        // interact with data
    }
}
```

This becomes very convenient as I use a Servlet Filter to ensure that the user has the appropriate privileges to access the service before passing the data, and then I can parse the incoming data (or load it, or whatever) and dump it into the attribute to be loaded.

If you don't want the above `Provider` approach, and you want the base class for accessing the attributes, then here you go:

```
public class RequestContextBean
{
    /**
     * The current request from the user.
     */
    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest request;

    /**
     * Get the attribute associated with the current {@link HttpServletRequest}.
     * @param name The attribute name.
     * @param type The expected type of the attribute.
     * @return {@code null} if the attribute does not exist, or if it does not
     *         match the {@code type}. Otherwise the appropriately casted
     *         attribute.
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code type} is {@code null}.
     */
    public <T> T getAttribute(String name, Class<T> type)
    {
        T value = null;
        Object attribute = request.getAttribute(name);

        if (type.isInstance(attribute))
        {
            value = type.cast(attribute);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

@Path("my/path/to")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public interface MyService
{
    @Path("service1")
    @POST
    Response postData();

    @Path("service2")
    @POST
    Response postOtherData();
}

@Component
public class MyServiceBean extends RequestContextBean implements MyService
{
    @Override
    public Response postData()
    {
        MyType data = getAttribute("some.name", MyType.class);
        // interact with data
    }

    @Override
    Response postOtherData()
    {
        MyOtherType data = getAttribute("other.name", MyOtherType.class);
        // interact with data
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE2**: I thought about my implementation of `AbstractAttributeInjectableProvider`, which is itself a generic class that only exists to provide `AttributeInjectable`'s for a given type, `Class<T>` and the supplied `AttributeParam`. It's far easier to provide a non-`abstract` implementation that is told its type (`Class<T>`) with each requested `AttributeParam`, thus avoiding a bunch of constructor-only implementations providing the type for you. This also avoids having to write code for every single type that you want to use with the `AttributeParam` annotation.

```
@Component
@Provider
public class AttributeParamInjectableProvider
        implements InjectableProvider<AttributeParam, Type>
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @return Always {@link ComponentScope#PerRequest}.
     */
    @Override
    public ComponentScope getScope()
    {
        return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
    }

    /**
     * Get an {@link AttributeInjectable} to inject the {@code parameter} for
     * the given {@code type}.
     * @param context Unused.
     * @param parameter The requested parameter
     * @param type The type of data to be returned.
     * @return {@code null} if {@code type} is not a {@link Class}. Otherwise
     *         an {@link AttributeInjectable}.
     */
    @Override
    public AttributeInjectable<?> getInjectable(ComponentContext context,
                                                AttributeParam parameter,
                                                Type type)
    {
        AttributeInjectable<?> injectable = null;

        // as long as it's something that we can work with...
        if (type instanceof Class)
        {
            injectable = getInjectable((Class<?>)type, parameter);
        }

        return injectable;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new {@link AttributeInjectable} for the given {@code type} and
     * {@code parameter}.
     * <p />
     * This is provided to avoid the support for generics without the need for
     * {@code SuppressWarnings} (avoided via indirection).
     * @param type The type of data to be returned.
     * @param parameter The requested parameter
     * @param <T> The type of data being accessed by the {@code param}.
     * @return Never {@code null}.
     */
    protected <T> AttributeInjectable<T> getInjectable(Class<T> type,
                                                       AttributeParam parameter)
    {
        return new AttributeInjectable<T>(type, parameter.value());
    }
}
```

Note: each `Injectable` is instantiated once at startup rather than per request, but they are invoked upon each incoming request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you initializing Jersey?

I will assume you are using Jersey using the jersey-spring servlet. In which case Jersey would by default initialize using Spring beans and hence your `Provider` has to be a Spring bean. Try adding a `@Named` (or if you do not use atinject `@Component` or one of the Spring annotaions) to your `Provider`.

[An example of using Injectable Providers](http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers/).

---

**Updated**: More clarity on the scope of injection:

The `Provider` has to be a Singleton, as for all practical purposes its a factory with scope tied to it and there is no need to construct a factory for every request. The injection itself would happen per request. In other words the `getInjectable` method would be called for every request. Did you get a chance to try that?

OTOH, if you extend the `SingletonTypeInjectableProvider` the same object would be injected into your resource every time.

I am not sure I completely understand your `Provider` implementation. I believe something like the following should work.

```
public class UserProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<AttributeParam, Users>{

    public UserProvider(){
        super(Users.class);
    }

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public Injectable<Users> getInjectable(ComponentContext cc, AttributeParam a) {

        String attributeValue = AnnotationUtils.getValue(a);

        return new Injectable<Users>(){

            public Users getValue() {
                System.out.println("Called"); //This should be called for each request
                return request.getAttribute(attributeValue);
            }

        };

    }

}
```

---

**Updated**: To provide more information on the injection types and contexts available in Jersey.

As you probably figured by now, if all you need is access to the `HttpServletRequest` then just directly injecting it into your `Resource` or `Provider` using the `@Context` annotation will get you that.

However, to pass those values to the Injectable one has to use a `AssistedProvider` or use an approach similar to yours. But again you can mitigate that if you inline your `Injectable` definition in the Provider and inject the `HttpServletRequest` into the `Provider` class. In that case the `Injectable` would be able to access the `HttpServletRequest` instance (since its there in scope). I just updated my example to show that approach.

Injection using `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` and `SingletonTypeInjectableProvider` are not the only two options you have to inject values into your resources. You could also inject using `*Param` values using a `StringReaderProvider`. Obviously such an injection is request scoped.

```
@Provider
@Named("userProviderParamInjector")
public class UserProviderParam implements StringReaderProvider<Users> {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public StringReader<Users> getStringReader(Class<?> type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns) {
        if(type.equals(Users.class) {
           return null;
        }

        String attributeValue = null;
        for(Annotation a : antns) {
            if((a.getClass().getSimpleName()).equals("AttributeParam")){
               attributeValue = (String)AnnotationUtils.getValue(a);
            }
        }

        return new StringReader<Users>(){
            public Users fromString(String string) {
                // Use the value of the *Param or ignore it and use the attributeValue of our custom annotation.
                return request.getAttribute(attributeValue);
            }

        };

    }

}
```

This `Provider` would be invoked for any `*Param` that you have in your resource. So with a `Provider` like the one above registered and a resource like the one below, the `Users` value would be injected into your resource method.

```
@Path("/user/")
@Named
public class UserResource {

    @Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Result<Users> get(@AttributeParam("foo") @PathParam("id") Users user) {
    ...
    }

}
```

But to be honest with you I consider this an abuse of the StringReaderProvider contract whereas the former technique of using `Injectable` feels cleaner.

Comment: Instantiating the Provider's as beans (or having them automatically picked up) seems to get them picked up, but I am for some reason forced to make them singletons. Do you have any idea why it requires me to make the `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` singleton scoped? If I force it into a request scope, it fails with an exception. The example was actually the original Injectable Provider example that got me onto this. The code examples that he provides are not the best (he combines the `Provider` with the `Injectable`). It's stupid that Jersey tried to abstract away the `ServletRequest`.

Comment: Updated with more information. In brief, the `Provider` being a singleton is a feature but a new value should be provided for each request.

Comment: Ah ha. I was misconstruing the purpose of the `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider`. Jersey immediately constructs the `Injectable`s that it decides that it needs after scanning the various Restful Services that it controls. I took "PerRequest" to mean that the `Provider` would be checked with each given request. I wanted to use the `Provider` to inject the `HttpServletRequest` into a new `AttributeInjectable` (my own type) to extract the `HttpServletRequest#getAttribute(String)` with the name given to the `AttributeParam`. This way my Restful Services could have attributes injected cleanly.

Comment: I am going to update my answer, but this lead to what I needed, although I still wish Jersey were a bit more flexible with accessing the current `HttpServletRequest` from the `Provider` interface rather than the much less useful `HttpContext` that it provides to `Injectable`s.

Comment: Thanks by the way. This is much cleaner. (And my last comment should have said "update my question," and not "update my answer")

Comment: You CAN easily access the HttpServletRequest if you want to. Just inject the HttpServletRequest into your Provider using the Context annotaion and you will have access to the *current* request. The key fact is that the value being injected is ThreadLocal so each getValue invocation would be operating on the "current" request.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work for some reason. That would be an even simpler solution. Before I went to sleep last night, I thought of a way to refactor the above code to make it even simpler (no extending required), and I will likely revise it tonight, and retry the @Context.

Comment: Mm., I just updated my examples to throw some more light on the approach I was thinking about...

Comment: one of the best question and answer I have seen so far on SO.. thanks :)