# How do you configure a JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter on a per-request basis?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Essentially, I have a MessageBodyWriter that writes objects as JSON, and I'd like to be able to control some aspects of the output based on which resource method handled the request. However, the default lifecycle of @Provider classes is singleton (one per JVM), so I can't inject an instance of some configuration object. This leaves me with 2 obvious workarounds:

1. **Use custom annotations**: Each call to writeTo(...) includes the list of annotations on the method that was invoked, so I could check for the existence of some annotation. However, JAX-RS methods are already pretty laden with metaprogramming.
2. **Use a ThreadLocal property map**: Assuming one request per thread, but this approach breaks encapsulation a bit. The resource methods needs to be aware that there is some other class out there, looking for this map.

Is there a way to change the lifecycle of the Provider itself? I am using Jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAX-RS 1.1 spec [requires that implementations support singleton providers and allows support for other lifecycles](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-400004.1) but doesn't suggest anything else along those lines. As far as I'm aware, pure Jersey doesn't support anything beyond singletons. With [the jersey-spring contrib module](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e1869), you get support for using Spring as Jersey's IoC container (where it gets its resource and provider instances from). I know Spring supports multiple lifecycles, including request, but I'm not sure if support for that is built into jersey-spring.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need a MessageBodyWriter Provider with per-request basis. If you just want to distinguish which methods are with JSON ouput and which are not, then `jersey-json` does already support.

And although the `@Provider` is singleton. You still can use per-request object within it like below.

```
@Provider
public class StViewProcessor implements ViewProcessor<ST> {     

    ......

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;


    public void writeTo(ST st, Viewable viewable, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        ...
    }


}
```

And if you want to inject your instance per request, you can have a look at `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider`. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944434/jersey-injectableprovider-not-picked-up-spring) about it.

Comment: To clarify, it's not distinguishing between JSON and not-JSON, but how to format the JSON, or perhaps filter it. So, ultimately the same writer is involved. Using the request object is pretty equivalent to ThreadLocal properties, but it's interesting that per-request contexts will be correctly injected at each request (did not know).

Comment: Yeah, per-request Objects with `@Context` are based on Thread Local Proxy. So you should not need to implement your own ThreadLocal property map to do the same thing.